# Record the results of an Excel cell indirectly subject to a randon number. I want to track only the negative values. They can be put in any order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I believe the title says it all. Need to record the results of a formula cell indirectly subject to a random number. The results can be put in a single column multi row format.

Comment: Almost impossible without VBA. I say almost because there's possibly some extremely tricky solution using the `Enable Iterative Calculation` option, together with circular references (self-referring cells) but it won't be a recommended solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, but is this what you are looking for?

```
Calculate   'Recalculated the random value in A1
If Range("a1").Value < 0 Then
'initially select B1 and then populate colummn B
    Selection.Value = Range("a1").Value
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
```

Comment: I use the f9 key in excel to randomize a portfolio of stock returns. This cell has a formula that shows the value of the portfolio, could be positive or negative or zero. If it goes negative I want to keep a record of the negative values in a column on the same excel sheet. Hopefully this can be done without VBA.

Comment: Normal calculation in an excel sheet calculates values currently present in it. You cant store/work with older values unless you manually save it or use VBA

Comment: Mr. Thomas thanks for the quick reply. I also came the same conclusion after about an hour. I am not a VBA person so i'm asking if the code you show above is VBA CODE to solve my problem?

Comment: Yes its a VBA code. Just press Alt+F11 then insert>module and type the code given above inside a sub
Sub test_code()
<place code here>
End Sub
after that just run your code by pressing F5